# Check all objects are available for Schema.describeSObjects()

Tags: apex, schema

I'm getting all the objects in an org with`Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` and then running a describe on the the list of all the names with `Schema.describeSObjects(objs)`.

This has been fine so far, but I've just run into an issue where one of the object names from the global describe is not valid:

> The Schema.describeSObject() methods does not support the knowledge__kav sobject as a parameter. If you are attempting to use a Knowledge Article Type, be sure to use the abstract KnowledgeArticleVersion instead.

Is there a list anywhere of all the objects not available to be passed in?
Or should I just avoid any '__kav' suffixed objects?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the list is other way round. You can get the list of all available SObjects that can be passed as argument to `describeSObjects(objs[])` by referring to [Standard Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm#topic-title).

From documentation:

> **Arguments**
>
> The `describeSObjects()` call takes in an array of sObjects.
>
> ..
>
> The specified value must be a valid object for your organization. For a complete list of objects, see [Standard Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm#topic-title).